# Outlook VBA to create a hyperlink to a specific Outlook object

Tags: vba, outlook

I know that Outlook supports handling of hyperlinks of the format:

```
 outlook:EntryID
```

where 
`EntryID` is the value of `olMail.EntryID`.

I'm looking to create a macro that will run on an Outlook mail item and copy an outlook: hyperlink like this to the clipboard as a hyperlink (not as plain text).

Building the URL string is easy and I can use `DataObject.SetText` and `DataObject.PutInClipboard` to put the URL in the clipboard as plan text, but how can I copy the string to the clipboard as a hyperlink?

In C# I would try something like:

```
SetText(String, TextDataFormat.Html)
```

Where `TextDataFormat` is a value in the `System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat` enum, but I'm not sure how to do something equivalent in VBA.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All .Net clipboard functionality is based on the Windows API functions. So, you can use [SetClipboardData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function in VBA which places data on the clipboard in a specified clipboard format. The first parameter can be a registered format or any of the standard clipboard formats. For more information, see [Standard Clipboard Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Registered Clipboard Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Registered_Clipboard_Formats).

Be aware, the Entry ID changes when an item is moved into another store, for example, from your Inbox to a Microsoft Exchange Server public folder, or from one Personal Folders (.pst) file to another .pst file. Solutions should not depend on the EntryID property to be unique unless items will not be moved. Moreover, a MAPI store provider assigns a unique ID string when an item is created in its store. That means you will get different entry IDs on PCs.

Comment: Combined with https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ee9e0d28-0f1e-467f-8d1d-1a86b2db2878/a-clipboard-object-for-vba-including-microsoft-word?forum=worddev I think that would have enough to go on. There are some challenges here that make me want to go another way.